# Lightning flows

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, screen-flow

How to call a screen flow from a button(quick action) in a lightning record page?

I need to have screens in the flow and need the flow to be executed on the click of a button.But screen flows are not available in quick actions.Is there any workaround like using lightning components or so.

Comment: Object specific quick actions support flow with screens. Doesn't that solve your problem? Or do you have a different business case?

Answer (score 1):

As tugce mentioned, an object-specific quick action will allow you to launch a screen flow by pressing an action button on a Lightning Record Page.

Make sure there is at least one active version of your screen flow, and add the action to the relevant page layout of course.

[image]

[image]